# Why is Nginx FastCGI cache STALE response slower than HIT response?

Tags: nginx, cache

I have strange problem with nginx microcache. When nginx serve STALE content, it takes too long.
My actual microacha part in config:

```
...
fastcgi_cache biznisto.sk;
fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$rt_session";
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 5m;
fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;
fastcgi_cache_lock on;
fastcgi_cache_revalidate on;
fastcgi_cache_background_update on;
fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie;
fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
...
```

Screens
STALE - wait 565ms
[image]
HIT - wait 59ms
[image]

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same scenario.  My understanding is it should serve the stale content with the same speed as a HIT, and then do a background refresh of the content for the next request.  But my experience is the same as yours, STALE is delayed the same as if it were not doing a background update but a real-time update.  Have you found any solution?

Comment: This seems to be similar: http://hg.nginx.org/nginx/rev/9552758a786e -- I am running nginx 1.12.1 and I wonder if this patch is not included?  I would love to solve this, and currently nginx 1.12.1 is the newest version I can use on my debian wheezy system.

Comment: I am using nginx/1.13.11, CentOS, still not solved problem :( But STALE isnt like MISS, it is faster. But when i use pingdom it says this strange results

Comment: For me, STALE performs the same as MISS.  From the link I shared, it's because of how it is waiting for the background process to finish.  I don't quite understand the purpose, but since 1.13.11 still hasn't solved it, that is disappointing news.  I guess I'll have to look to Varnish.

Comment: Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/nginx/comments/j2jmr4/nginx_cache_status_stale/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **fastcgi_cache_background_update** directive allows updating an expired cache item while the stale cached response is being returned to the client.

If, however, the response is fully returned, but updating is not yet finished, it will delay subsequent actions, including processing of additional requests on the same connection, and/or the closing of the connection.

This behaviour ensures that:

- a client cannot impose uncontrolled load on the server, assuming various limitations like limit_conn are in place
- the overall operation is usually better and, in the worst case, is not worse than without background update.

https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1329